# WinAPI - CryptDecrypt (AES) decrypts data but still raises an error

Tags: winapi, encryption, openssl, aes, cryptoapi

A particular issue with Windows CryptoAPI is giving me a headache with testing as I can't agree on a solution.  I am aware of CryptoAPI-NG taking precedence in the support & dev world, but that is a separate issue irrelevant to the question.

The jist: CryptDecrypt() correctly places the expected plaintext into the passed buffer given a known binary key and IV, yet the function itself will sometimes (explained below) returns FALSE and sets the last error to NTE_BAD_DATA (0x80090005).

Without posting the entire source (of a project), I will walk through the steps of the process.
For those wondering the "why?" in this quest, I need to (as close to) seamlessly allow various crypto suites (AES/RSA on OpenSSL/CryptoAPI/mbedTLS/etc) to communicate with each other.  Since Windows likes to do many things its own way despite the convenience of convention, I'm running into some massive potholes along the way.

#### Acquiring CSP handle

```
    if (!CryptAcquireContextW(&(pCtx->hProvider), NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        iRetval = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext() failed with error %d (0x%X)\r\n", iRetval, iRetval);
        return iRetval;
    }
```

NOTE: passing 0 or `NULL` to the `dwFlags` parameter of CryptAcquireContext() did not solve the problem (this has been suggested on similar questions).

#### Importing the key

```
typedef struct _CRYPTOAPI_AES128_KEYBLOB
{
    BLOBHEADER blbHdr;
    DWORD dwKeySize;
    BYTE ucKeyBytes[16];
} CRYPTOAPI_AES128_KEYBLOB; // structure definition

CRYPTOAPI_AES128_KEYBLOB aes128blob = { 0 };
aes128blob.blbHdr.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
aes128blob.blbHdr.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
aes128blob.blbHdr.aiKeyAlg = pCtx->uiAlg;
aes128blob.dwKeySize = dwKeyLen;
memcpy_s(aes128blob.ucKeyBytes, sizeof(aes128blob.ucKeyBytes), lpKey, dwKeyLen);
if (!CryptImportKey(pCtx->hProvider, (LPCBYTE)&aes128blob, sizeof(aes128blob), (HCRYPTKEY)0, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &(pCtx->hKey)))
{
    iRetval = GetLastError();
    printf("CryptImportKey() failed with error %d (0x%X)\r\n", iRetval, iRetval);
}
```

`lpKey` and `dwKeyLen` are passed parameters for the binary key and its length (16 in this case), respectively.  Function succeeds without errors.

#### Decrypting the data

```
    DWORD dwAesMode = CRYPT_MODE_CBC;
    DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;

    if (!CryptSetKeyParam(pCtx->hKey, KP_MODE, (LPCBYTE)&dwAesMode, 0))
    {
        iRetval = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptSetKeyParam() failed with error %d (0x%X)\r\n", iRetval, iRetval);
        return iRetval;
    }

    if (!CryptSetKeyParam(pCtx->hKey, KP_IV, (LPCBYTE)ucIv, 0))
    {
        iRetval = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptSetKeyParam() failed with error %d (0x%X)\r\n", iRetval, iRetval);
        return iRetval;
    }

    memcpy_s(ucOutput, dwInputLen, lpInput, dwInputLen);
    dwBufferSize = dwInputLen;
    if (!CryptDecrypt(pCtx->hKey, (HCRYPTHASH)0, TRUE, 0, ucOutput, &dwBufferSize))
    {
        iRetval = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptDecrypt() failed with error %d (0x%X)\r\n", iRetval, iRetval);
        return iRetval;
    }
```

The `ucOutput` points to a buffer that is appropriately sized to be a multiple of 16 bytes. `lpInput` is the ciphertext and `dwInputLen` is its length (also a multiple of 16).

#### "Fails sometimes?"

From what I've noticed, CryptDecrypt() only raises this error when the plaintext size (without added padding) is a multiple of 16 bytes (AES block size).  Assume I encrypt 9 bytes of data using CryptEncrypt()...  7 bytes of padding are added to the plaintext before encryption. This ciphertext is decrypted without a problem (no NTE_BAD_DATA raised).

Now, I did try something that seems to shut the errors up.. but according to MSDN is not good practice.  Setting the bFinal parameter of [CryptDecrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecrypt) to FALSE, even when it is in fact the only block to decrypt, seems to ignore the padding expectation if the plaintext size is a multiple of 16 bytes.

```
CryptDecrypt(pCtx->hKey, (HCRYPTHASH)0, FALSE, 0, ucOutput, &dwBufferSize)
```

The only downside I see to this approach is having to know the exact plaintext size with each message (in order to ignore the padding bytes that now won't be trimmed by the OS call).  Depending on the protocol, the size can be embedded into the first few bytes of the plaintext itself.  Am I right about this, or are there more technical aspects I'm blissfully ignoring?

#### Appendix

To replicate my tests yourself, here are two datasets I used to confirm proper functioning of AES-128 using CryptoAPI.

```
const BYTE* ucAes128Test1Ptx = "\x6b\xc1\xbe\xe2\x2e\x40\x9f\x96\xe9\x3d\x7e\x11\x73\x93\x17\x2a";
const BYTE* ucAes128Test1Key = "\x2b\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c";
const BYTE ucAes128Test1Iv[16] = "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f";
const BYTE* ucAes128Test1Cptx = "\x76\x49\xab\xac\x81\x19\xb2\x46\xce\xe9\x8e\x9b\x12\xe9\x19\x7d";

const BYTE* ucAes128Test2Ptx = "\xae\x2d\x8a\x57\x1e\x03\xac\x9c\x9e\xb7\x6f\xac\x45\xaf\x8e\x51";
const BYTE* ucAes128Test2Key = "\x2b\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c";
const BYTE ucAes128Test2Iv[16] = "\x76\x49\xab\xac\x81\x19\xb2\x46\xce\xe9\x8e\x9b\x12\xe9\x19\x7d";
const BYTE* ucAes128Test2Cptx = "\x50\x86\xcb\x9b\x50\x72\x19\xee\x95\xdb\x11\x3a\x91\x76\x78\xb2";
```

All buffers are 16 bytes long, and have been tested with CryptoAPI's CryptEncrypt (success) and CryptDecrypt (success with errors).

Comment: when you encrypt 16 bytes, size of encrypted data will be 32. in general `cbEncrypted = ((cbPlain + 16) & ~15)`. so on decrypt input buffer must be 32 bytes, not  16. you not show your encrypt code

Comment: from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) : If the length of the original data is an integer multiple of the block size _B_, then an extra block of bytes with value _B_ is added... so you're right, and it would seem that the OS calls account for this as well.  The test vectors were pulled from [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-23/openssl/test/evptests.txt.auto.html) but don't seem to employ the use of pkcs7 ... thank you

Comment: how you think - where is length of original block is stored ? it can be 1 byte of 15 - but encrypted block is 16 in both case - so where length ? but if you use 16 bytes (or exactly blocksize) - need extra block for length. i test with your data - https://pastebin.com/DdGqv1SB . how you can see - encrypted data is 32 bytes - low 16 bytes the the same as your, but you lost high 16

Answer (score 0):

With block encryption algorithms such as AES you need to add padding to the data being encrypted up to a multiple of the block length.

You can find out the size of the required encryption buffer directly by making an additional call to "CryptEncrypt" with a NULL buffer before the actual encryption:

```
dwBuffSize = dwDataLen  // dwDataLen is the actual length of the data being encrpyted
CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, &dwBuffSize, 0)
dwPadding = dwBuffsize - dwDataLen  // number of padding characters you need to add in the actual encryption process
```

Then append "dwPadding" number of characters (NULL works fine) to the data being encrypted and you will no longer get "Bad Data" errors in decryption.

The "CryptDecrypt" function already knows about padding and will return the actual size of the decryption buffer in one go so you will know exactly where your decrypted data ends.

In your particular example, the "ucOutput" buffer needs to be exactly "dwInputLen" bytes long. "CryptDecrypt" assumes the data has already been padded accordingly before encryption so the decryption buffer needs to be the exact size of the ciphertext. Do not add anything to it.